# JQuery - Get all attributes of an XML element

Tags: jquery, xml, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to get an array of all the attributes of an element in an XML response.

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() {
  console.info($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
  ...
```

This returns the correct value for ows_Title, but I want to find out all the attributes that the z:row has.  How can I do that and have it work in ALL browsers?  I have a method working for FF and Chrome, but it doesn't work in IE.  IE doesn't seem to recognize that an XML element has attributes, but it sees them when I look specifically for one like "ows_Title".

What about this:

```
for(var key in this.attributes) {
  if(!isNaN(key)) {
    if(!prefix || this.attributes[key].name.substr(0,prefix.length) == prefix) {
      attributes.push(this.attributes[key].name);
    }
  }
}
```

THIS DOESN'T DO ANYTHING IN IE, even though it comes up with a NamedNodeMap when I do console.info(this.attributes):

```
for(var key in this.attributes) {
  alert("test");
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I ended up just iterating.

```
if(jQuery) {
  jQuery.fn.listAttributes = function() {
    var attributes = new Array();
    $(this).each(function() {
      for (var i=0; i<this.attributes.length; i++)
      {
        attributes.push(this.attributes.item(i).nodeName);
      }
    });
    return attributes;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() {
    console.info(this.attributes);
...
```

Comment: It comes up with a "NamedNodeMap" with the right number of attributes -- what do I do with that?

Comment: I added another thing I'm trying into the original post -- look at the "What about this:" part.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.net with your full example ?

Comment: I'm using this with SharePoint 2010 lists, so I'm not sure how to show you a functioning example, but here is the code I'm using to accomplish the task so far:

Comment: I figured a way around it.


    for (var i=0; i<this.attributes.length; i++)
        {
         attributes.push(this.attributes.item(i).nodeName);
         console.info(this.attributes.item(i).nodeName);
        }

I also had some arguments mixed up in the jquery isArray function, but it seemed to work anyways in FF and Chrome.  Both together did the trick.